# How do I use GHCSlave without signing errors?

Tags: ios, haskell, cross-compiling, template-haskell

I have gotten [`ghc-slave`](https://github.com/zw3rk/ghc-slave) to build for an iPhone 6S running iOS 12.0.1. I put this into a helper script so that I don't confuse `cabal` with constantly changing IP addresses:

**`connect_to_iphone`**

```sh
#!/bin/bash
exec iserv-proxy "$@" <iphone ip> <port>
```

I started GHCSlave on the iPhone, and I trusted my developer certificate as it asked.

I then cloned `singletons`, and tried to compile it.

```sh
git clone https://github.com/goldfirere/singletons
cd singletons
cabal --with-ghc=aarch64-apple-ios-ghc \
      --with-ghc-pkg=aarch64-apple-ios-ghc-pkg \
      --with-gcc=aarch64-apple-ios-clang \
      --with-ld=aarch64-apple-ios-ld \
      --hsc2hs-options=--cross-compile \
      --disable-shared \
      --configure-option=--host=aarch64-apple-ios
      --ghc-options=-fexternal-interpreter \
      --ghc-options=-pgmi=/path/to/connect_to_iphone
      new-configure
cabal new-build
```

When building `th-lift-instances`, TH was first needed. GHCSlave on the iPhone showed that the libraries were being sent over to run the TH. However, the moment execution of the TH actually began, GHCSlave crashed. The logs from XCode show

```
...
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGKILL - CODESIGNING)
...
Termination Reason: Namespace CODESIGNING, Code 0x2
...
```

I'm not sure where to get started fixing this. How do I use GHCSlave without signing errors?